# WPF - Drop shadow on the window's background PNG image

Tags: wpf

I have got the background of my window as a PNG image

```
<Window.Background>

  <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.png" Viewport="0,0,1,1"/>

</Window.Background>
```

How can i drop a shadow to the PNG background image to take the same shape as the image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <Window.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect/>
</Window.Effect>

<Window.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.png" Viewport="0,0,1,1"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Along with your Background set.. Set the `Window's Effect` as `DropShadowEffect`.

This might be no use since the shadow falls outside of the window and it will not be visible.

I would suggest you to have a `Panel` or `Border` and set `Margin` for that. Now set the `Background` and `Effect` to that.. it will be visible.

```
<Border Margin="10">
   <Border.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect/>
   </Border.Effect>

   <Border.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="image.png" Viewport="0,0,1,1"/>
   </Border.Background>
</Border>
```